# What is the best way to put a char* in between another one multiple times in c++?

Tags: c++, string, char, concatenation

I have a `char*` that looks like:

```
opt = "abcdefghijklmnop";
```

Now I have another `(const) char*` that is like;

```
home = getenv("HOME");
```

What I want to do is changing the `char* opt` by putting the `char* home` in between, something like:

```
opt = "a" + home + "b" + home + "c" + home + ...;
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Use `std::string`.

Comment: **Define** what you mean by "best". Otherwise this question is just seeking subjective opinion. I've voted to close as such.

Answer (score 4):

If we define "best" as how error prone it is and take into account ease of use then in my opinion the best way is not to use a `char*` and instead use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.  With a `std::string` you can do

```
std::string foo = "World";
std::string builder = "Hello " + foo + "!";
```

Result

```
Hello World!
```

`std::string` also has a constructor that takes a `const char*` or a `char*` so you can still use it with your functions that return those.  There is also a `c_str()` member function what will return a `const char*` so you can still use it with functions that take either a `const char*` or a `char*`

Comment: This is the best way to go, particularly since the question is tagged `C++`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, There is no such thing as perfection.  Splitting hairs over the definition of "best" in this case is not necessary.  Sometimes questions are too vague, but this one is worthy.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I translate "best" to least error prone and take into account ease of use.  `std::string` offers both of those and so that is "best" IMHO.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Then you should add you definition to the answer, and explain e.g. why in your opinion that's less errror prone and easier than sequential output, say.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf just did

Comment: To be fair, if the OP had 78K in SO reputation, "best" would be expected to mean something pretty advanced, regarding performance, for one example.  But the OP has a rep of only 40, so the context is someone just learning and seeking guidance.

Comment: I think a reasonable interpretation of "best" might be "linear time". Then something like [a simple loop extending the string in each iteration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e3733a480286fa5) could be an answer, when supplanted with technical details about why it is linear time. But until the OP clarifies, if ever, we can't really know what an answer would be. IMHO. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

you better to use std::string as said by @kerrek SB. if using char * is necessary, you can use strcpy function as described [here](http://Channel9.msdn.com)

Comment: you are the boss @Cheers  :)

Comment: I would add, in the case of *needing* char*, that `strcat()` with `strcpy()` would be helpful.